# Python Requests: 'The Authorization header is missing'

Tags: python, api, python-requests, get, http-status-codes

I'm trying to make an username checker for Ubisoft using Python's requests.
When I run my code I always get a status code 200, which should indicate that the username is available, even when the username is taken. I checked the [request link](https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v2/profiles?nameOnPlatform=test&platformType=uplay) and it says:

> {"moreInfo":"","errorCode":3,"httpCode":401,"errorContext":"Shipyard.Profiles.Services","message":"The Authorization header is missing","environment":"prod","additionalDetails":{},"transactionTime":"2021-05-24T17:27:50.9065561Z","transactionId":"5d4edaf2-8e8f-4e3f-9736-fce6aea82e32"}

However, I added `'Authorization':token` to my code with token being an input you get from the authority website after logging in.

My code:

```
import requests
import json

def check():
    username = input("What name to check? :")
    print(" ")
    token = input("Enter token: ")

    r = requests.get("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v2/profiles?nameOnPlatform=" + username + "&platformType=uplay", headers = {
                'Method':'GET',
                'Authority':'public-ubiservices.ubi.com',
                'Ubi-AppId':'c5393f10-7ac7-4b4f-90fa-21f8f3451a04',
                'Authorization': token,
                'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
                'Ubi-RequestedPlatformType':'uplay',
                })
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.text)

print("Press ENTER to start checking")
input("")
check()
```

Edit: Added r.text

r.text gives this as output for what should be a taken username (username = test)

```
200
{"profiles":[{"profileId":"21067093-822e-497d-ae8a-5d171573f6c8","userId":"21067093-822e-497d-ae8a-5d171573f6c8","platformType":"uplay","idOnPlatform":"21067093-822E-497D-AE8A-5D171573F6C8","nameOnPlatform":"test"}]}
```

and r.text gives this as output for a what should be available username (username = test815581m)

```
200
{"profiles":[]}
```

Comment: Try using `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token`

Comment: @geobreze Gives me a 401 status code

Comment: Please, add output of `r.text` to a post. It may be caused by invalid token

Comment: @geobreze added it to the post

Comment: So, what's the problem with an application? You're getting a response.

Comment: @geobreze I thought that the way to make this would be by saying if r.status_code == 200, then the username is available and that if r.status_code == 404, the username would be taken. But I can change the code around to something like if r.text = {"profiles":[]}, then username is available, else: unavailable. (My bad if it looks messy but I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: By specification of HTTP status codes, status code 200 is returned when the application processed the request successfully. You can check whether user exists or not by checking length of `profiles` array. Something like `userWasFound = len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0`

Comment: @geobreze as in `userWasFound = len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0 if userWasFound == False: print(username + ' is available') if userWasFound == True: print(username + ' is taken')`?

Comment: Yep, this looks correct for me